# Python xmlsec XML Signature Value mismatch

Tags: python-3.x, lxml, xml-signature, python-cryptography

I am new to xml signatures and currently I am using xmlsec to generate a signed xml. I do this with some modifications on the sample code:

```
from lxml import etree
import xmlsec

parser = etree.XMLParser(remove_blank_text=True)
template = etree.parse('unsigned.xml', parser).getroot()

signature_node = xmlsec.tree.find_node(template, xmlsec.constants.NodeSignature)
ctx = xmlsec.SignatureContext()
key = xmlsec.Key.from_file('keys/private_key.pem', xmlsec.constants.KeyDataFormatPem)
ctx.key = key
sig_ = ctx.sign(signature_node)
formated = etree.tostring(template)
with open('signed_test.xml', 'wb') as the_file:
    the_file.write(formated)
```

Now I have signed XML, and from here I am trying to learn where or how the values get generated. I am following [this](https://www.xml.com/pub/a/2001/08/08/xmldsig.html) for context. I am able to verify the `DigestValue` and now I am trying to get the `SignatureValue`. From the link and some other questions here in stackoverflow, I just need to:

1. Canonized the whole `SignedInfo` element
2. Hash the result
3. Sign the Hash

In order to get the signature value. I am canonizing the `SignedInfo` Element using `lxml`:

```
from lxml import etree

parser = etree.XMLParser(remove_blank_text=True)
xmlTree = etree.parse('signed_info.xml', parser)
root = xmlTree.getroot()
formated = etree.tostring(root, method='c14n', exclusive=True)
# Write to file
with open('canon_sinfo.xml', 'wb') as the_file:
    the_file.write(formated)
```

For info the following is the resulting `SignedInfo`:

```
<SignedInfo><CanonicalizationMethod Algorithm="http://www.w3.org/2001/10/xml-exc-c14n#"></CanonicalizationMethod><SignatureMethod Algorithm="http://www.w3.org/2001/04/xmldsig-more#rsa-sha256"></SignatureMethod><Reference URI="#obj"><Transforms><Transform Algorithm="http://www.w3.org/2000/09/xmldsig#base64"></Transform></Transforms><DigestMethod Algorithm="http://www.w3.org/2001/04/xmlenc#sha256"></DigestMethod><DigestValue>izbIdQ4tSAg6VKGpr1zd6kU9QpVQi/Bcwxjxu/k2oKk=</DigestValue></Reference></SignedInfo>
```

I am using [cryptography](https://cryptography.io/en/latest/) to try and generate the `SignatureValue` however, I cannot get the same result as that of what xmlsec generated.

Here is my code snippet in doing so:

```
sign_info = '''String of the Sign Info'''
digest_sinfo = hashes.Hash(hashes.SHA256(), backend=default_backend())
digest_sinfo.update(bytes(sign_info, 'utf-8'))
digested_sinfo = digest_sinfo.finalize()

# Load private_key here...

# Sign the message
signature_1v15 = private_key.sign(
    digested_sinfo,
    padding.PKCS1v15(),
    hashes.SHA256()
)
```

I also tried loading the `SignedInfo` into a seperate file, however I still get a mismatched SignatureValue. How do I accomplish this?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your issue is that you do the hashing twice. The `sign()` function does the hashing for you so you can skip the middle part.

Just call the `sign()` with your canonized SignedInfo element:

```
signature_1v15 = private_key.sign(
    sign_info,
    padding.PKCS1v15(),
    hashes.SHA256()
)
```